# jQuery-File-Upload(Blueimp) with custom ajax under October CMS

Tags: components, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, octobercms

Trying to create a component under October CMS which should allow frontend multiple fileuploads. I try to integrate in already exiting form the Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload Plugin and because October CMS uses an integrated ajax Framework which allows data Submission to Component method I would use this ajax method instead what from default by Blueimp

so a normal fileupload looks like

```
$('#gallery').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'path/to/controller'

});
```

but instead I would like to use something like

```
$('#gallery').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    add: function (e, data) {
        data.submit();
        $.request('onUploads', {

            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

            }
        })
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Request class from Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#files) which OctoberCMS sits on top of. Basically you go to the code section of your layout file and add

```
function onUploads()
{
    // Get the file
    $file = Request::file('somefile');

    // Code to do something with it
    // enter code here
}
```

Based on what you are trying to achieve you can write appropriate code to upload it. For example, in [my Social Login plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/mohsin-social) i use methods of [this class](https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Attach/File.php) to fetch photos from the chosen Social network and create a relation between the plugin's Social model and the uploaded file so that a frontend user may output the photo as a display photo in their web app.

Another good way to do it would be to directly upload it into the themes directory by doing something like `Request::file('somefile')->move(app_path() . '/themes/yourtheme/assets/uploads/');` but then you will need to add code to limit the upload size and also to fix the file names. Feel free to make a comment if you need help on achieving something particularly. gl hf